# MS Access, how to find Entries that don't appear in another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an MS Access database with a table called `Numbers` which just contains a list of numbers between 0 and 100000 inclusive with no duplicates as the field `Number` (data type Number with length Long Integer) (Easiest way I could fine to create a range of numbers within Access). I also have a query called `AssetNumbers` which extracts the numbers contained within a text field of another table as `AssetNumber` (return of Vba function, also Long Integer), it's likely there are duplicates within this data set.

I need to find which numbers are present in the `Numbers` table which don't appear in the `AssetNumbers` table, I have created a query using the Query wizard within Access which has given me the following query. This appears to match up with other examples I have found through searching.

```
SELECT Numbers.Number
FROM Numbers LEFT JOIN AssetNumbersON Numbers.[Number] = AssetNumbers.[AssetNumber]
WHERE (((AssetNumbers.AssetNumber) Is Null));
```

When I try to view the output of this query Access throws a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error. What is causing this error and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having the comparison `WHERE (((AssetNumbers.AssetNumber) Is Null))`, I assume this was because `AssetNumber` was the return from a function rather than a static value. I managed to work around this by using another field from the `AssetNumbers` table for comparison.

Comment: `NOT EXIST` method of SQL may be more easier?